# Replica node never recover after rewind in Zalando operator

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I making a POC, in my test I killed the primary node, other node take the primary role, the new replica rewind.... but dead whit this messages:

```
2021-03-15 17:29:58,156 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:29:58,156 INFO: restarting after failure in progress
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
2021-03-15 17:30:08,156 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:08,156 INFO: restarting after failure in progress
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
2021-03-15 17:30:18,156 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:18,156 INFO: restarting after failure in progress
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
2021-03-15 17:30:28,156 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:28,156 INFO: restarting after failure in progress
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
2021-03-15 17:30:28,928 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:28,929 INFO: Still starting up as a standby.
2021-03-15 17:30:28,929 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:28,929 INFO: does not have lock
2021-03-15 17:30:28,929 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2021-03-15 17:30:29,250 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2021-03-15 17:30:29,252 WARNING: Retry got exception: 'connection problems'
2021-03-15 17:30:29,252 INFO: Error communicating with PostgreSQL. Will try again later
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
2021-03-15 17:30:38,929 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:38,929 INFO: Still starting up as a standby.
2021-03-15 17:30:38,930 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:38,930 INFO: does not have lock
2021-03-15 17:30:38,930 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2021-03-15 17:30:39,451 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2021-03-15 17:30:39,452 WARNING: Retry got exception: 'connection problems'
2021-03-15 17:30:39,453 INFO: Error communicating with PostgreSQL. Will try again later
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
2021-03-15 17:30:48,929 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:48,929 INFO: Still starting up as a standby.
2021-03-15 17:30:48,930 INFO: Lock owner: poc-db-test-22-1tb-1; I am poc-db-test-22-1tb-3
2021-03-15 17:30:48,930 INFO: does not have lock
2021-03-15 17:30:48,930 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2021-03-15 17:30:49,571 INFO: establishing a new patroni connection to the postgres cluster
2021-03-15 17:30:49,573 WARNING: Retry got exception: 'connection problems'
2021-03-15 17:30:49,573 INFO: Error communicating with PostgreSQL. Will try again later
/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections
```

the deploy yml

```
apiVersion: "acid.zalan.do/v1"
kind: postgresql
metadata:
  name: poc-db-test-22-1tb
  namespace: mdbs
spec:
  teamId: mdbs
  volume:
    size: 1Ti
  numberOfInstances: 4
  enableConnectionPooler: true  # enable/disable connection pooler deployment
  enableReplicaConnectionPooler: true # set to enable connectionPooler for replica service

  enableMasterLoadBalancer: true
  enableReplicaLoadBalancer: true
  allowedSourceRanges:  # load balancers' source ranges for both master and replica services
  - 127.0.0.1/32
  - 0.0.0.0/0

  users:
    daf:  # database owner
    - superuser
    - createdb
    app_user: #
    other_app: []
    one_app: #

  databases:
    someappdb1: app_user
    someappdb2: daf
    someappdb3: other_app

  postgresql:
    version: "12"
```

After check, I have 2 nodes down with the same problem

```
kubectl get pods -l application=spilo -L spilo-role -n mdbs -o wide                                                                                                       

NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP               NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES   SPILO-ROLE
poc-db-test-22-1tb-0   1/1     Running   0          30m     10.237.192.216   yul1-r13-u15   <none>           <none>
poc-db-test-22-1tb-1   1/1     Running   0          56m     10.237.197.90    yul1-r11-u27   <none>           <none>            master
poc-db-test-22-1tb-2   1/1     Running   0          56m     10.237.197.91    yul1-r11-u26   <none>           <none>            replica
poc-db-test-22-1tb-3   1/1     Running   0          82s     10.237.197.82    yul1-r12-u24   <none>           <none>
```

Can anyone help me trying to understand what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After go inside the docker, exec a patronictl -c ... reinit,  wait and your node will be online again....❗